# Hazelcast PagingPredicate performance

Tags: hazelcast

I'am trying to use PagingPredicate for map with only 340 entries. For first page with pageSize=15 it tooks about 15 ms to retrieve result, but for last page it tooks 250 ms. is it normal result?

code example:

```
    public List<NaturalPerson> getNaturalPersonByNameAndUser(String name, User user, int offset, int limit) {

        final PagingPredicate pagingPredicate = new PagingPredicate(new NaturalPersonPredicate(name,user), /*naturalPersonComparator,*/ limit);

        for(int i = 0; i< offset; i = i + limit){
            pagingPredicate.nextPage();
        }

        return Lists.newArrayList(naturalPersonMap.values(pagingPredicate));
    }
```

Comment: This is an old question, but for concerns about the performance of PagingPredicate in general, see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/10828 which has some analysis and a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends. How many times did you run the test btw? Writing a microbenchmark is quite complicated. Personally I use JMH for it.

Can you try it with JMH and see if the numbers still the same?

For an example with Hazelcast:
https://github.com/hazelcast/performancetop5/tree/master/item1